# How to add working query box to portfolioitemstreegrid app

Tags: rally

We wanted to use the portfolioitemstreegrid(https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/portfolioitemstreegrid) app since there was an issue with the old PortfolioDrilldownApp.  we were able to add the edit app setting options by adding:

```
getSettingsFields: function () {
var fields = this.callParent(arguments);
    fields.push({
    type: 'query'
  });

  return fields;
},
```

but that doesn't filter anything it just shows the box.
What do we need to add to get the query box to work.  The app has a filter already but it isn't flexible enough for us to run the queries we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hoped too that doing something like this will allow wiring up of query into the treegrid filter, but **it does not work**. There is no `storeConfig` on a treegrid:

```
if (this.getSetting('query')) {
    config.storeConfig.filters = [Rally.data.QueryFilter.fromQueryString(this.getSetting('query'))];             
}
```

In a month or so a new hierarchical tree grid app will become available, and it will take a query from the app settings dialog. I would not suggest extending this [portfolioitemstreegrid](https://github.com/RallySoftware/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/portfolioitemstreegrid), also because it is using the head (unstable) version 'x' of AppSDK2.